# Issues with controlled components (checkboxes) and RESTful mock in simple react app?

Tags: reactjs

I am using the jsonplaceholder to mock my data requests, but I'm running into some issues with controlled components via the checkboxes. The two methods that are giving me trouble are uncompleteTask()/completeTask(), as when I try to click the checkbox it completely wipes out the entire list of posts.

My goal is to be able to sort based on complete/id/title and check/uncheck each task. Any help would be appreciated....

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const restfulAPI = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { filter: "id", tasks: []};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`${restfulAPI}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(tasks => this.setState({ tasks }));
  }

  uncompleteTask = id => {
    fetch(`${restfulAPI}/${id}`, {
      method: "PATCH",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        completed: false
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        let newTasks = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.tasks.length; i++) {
          newTasks = newTasks.concat(
            json.id === this.state.tasks[i].id
              ? { ...this.state.tasks[i], completed: false }
              : this.state.tasks[i]
          );
        }
        this.setState({
          tasks: newTasks
        });
      });
  };

  completeTask = id => {
    fetch(`${restfulAPI}/${id}`, {
      method: "PATCH",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        completed: true
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        let newTasks = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.tasks.length; i++) {
          newTasks = newTasks.concat(
            json.id === this.state.tasks[i].id
              ? { ...this.state.tasks[i], completed: true }
              : this.state.tasks[i]
          );
        }
        this.setState({
          tasks: newTasks
        });
      });
  };

  getSortedTasks = () => {
    return this.state.tasks.sort((a, b) => {
      if (this.state.filter === "id") {
        return a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1;
      }

      if (this.state.filter === "completed") {
        return a.completed ? -1 : 1;
      }

      if (this.state.filter === "title") return a.title > b.title ? 1: -1;
    });
  };

  setFilterCompleted = () => {
    this.setState({ filter: "completed" });
  }

  setFilterId = () => {
    this.setState({ filter: "id" });
  }

  setFilterTitle = () => {
    this.setState({ filter: "title" });
  }

  addTask = () => {
    const task = document.getElementById("newTask").value;
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title: task,
        userId: 1,
        completed: false
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({ tasks: this.state.tasks.concat({ ...json, id: this.state.tasks.length + 1 }) }));
  };


  render() {
    const tasks = this.getSortedTasks();

    return (
      <div className="main">
        <div>
          Add Task: <input id="newTask" />
          <button onClick={this.addTask}>Add</button>
        </div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th onClick={this.setFilterCompleted}>✓</th>
              <th onClick={this.setFilterId}>ID</th>
              <th onClick={this.setFilterTitle}>Task</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {tasks.map(task => (
              <tr key={task.id}>
                <td>
                  {task.completed ? (
                    <input
                      onChange={this.uncompleteTask}
                      checked
                      type="checkbox"
                    />
                  ) : (
                    <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.completeTask} />
                  )}
                </td>
                <td>{task.id}</td>
                <td className="strikethrough">{task.title}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because `concat` does not modify `newTasks`, it returns the result which will be two array concatenated.

your `newTasks` is always an empty array

Try this:

```
        let newTasks = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.tasks.length; i++) {
          newTasks = newTasks.concat(
            json.id === this.state.tasks[i].id
              ? { ...this.state.tasks[i], completed: false }
              : this.state.tasks[i]
          );
        }
        this.setState({
          tasks: newTasks
        });
```

just to make it a bit clearer

```
let a = [1];
let b = [2,3];
let result = a.concat(b);
// a = [1]; b = [2,3]; result = [1,2,3];
```

Read more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

Comment: this makes sense, but for some reason the completed tasks cant revert back to uncomplete even with the modifications :/

Comment: I should be able to mock a PATCH right? even when I checkbox my first ID it doesnt seem to update the state of the task obj

Comment: i will update my code above. Still unable to toggle checkboxes :(

Comment: @Chris what exactly is not working? what is inside json? and what is inside state?

Comment: so tasks is an array of objects with each task being an object. One of the properties on each task is completed and I am simply unable to make it update this property.

Comment: @Chris can you console.log `json`, `this.state.tasks`, and `newTasks`, and see whats missing? do you have the correct array inside `newTasks`?

Comment: in order: json logs {completed: false}/ this.state.tasks logs Array(200) and when I dig into a task that I clicked it still has completed: true/ newTasks also returns an array(200) that has completed:true for the property I clicked on despite me wanting this one to be false

Comment: so I must be getting the right response in my json but doing something wrong to build up the new list?

Comment: @Chris so you are saying your `json={completed: false}` ? in your code you access property `json.id`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191189/discussion-between-chris-and-alexandr-zavalii).